# What Sonarqube scanner is responsible for collecting code duplication analysis for Java?

Tags: java, scala, sonarqube

I using JaCoCo + Scoverage for a project with a mixed codebase (Java (using JUnit), Scala (using Scalatest)). I'm not seeing any code duplication being reported and I have clearly added some copy/pasted code (in more than a few places; around 10 lines).

I don't see any of this as being reported as duplicate code. Is there some plugin I need for Gradle, or in Sonarqube that handles this?

I am not seeing it neither for the Java code, nor for the Scala code (I know that `sonar-scala` doesn't currently support such reports, but I was hoping that there would be some for Java.

We're using Sonarqube 6.7.6.

What do I need to enable to get this working?

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: @achAmháin: The goal of this isn't to get it to work in an IDE, but via command-line analysis, so that we could publish these results to Sonarqube.

Comment: Do you use the sonar-pmd plugin?

Comment: No, I'm not. Is this the one responsible for this?

Comment: i am not sure. I think it is implemented in the scanner, see https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/tree/master/sonar-scanner-engine/src/main/java/org/sonar/scanner/cpd